# Assigning function to a select created with PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a main select tag "category" which onchange calls a php script to 'echo' a new select tag:

```
   <select id="category" onchange="showme(this);">
       <option value="txt">text</option>
       <option value="img">image</option>
       <option value="htm">html</option>
       <option value="aud">Audio</option>
   </select>
```

And here is the function that calls the PHP script:

```
function showme(str) {  
    var e = document.getElementById("country");
    var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;      
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("channels").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {   
            document.getElementById("channels").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","lstavai.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

And here my PHP script :

```
<?php 
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $files = glob('../dsx/'.$q.'/*.txt');
    echo '<select id="Subme" onchange="showSubme(this);">';
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $file = pathinfo($file);    
        echo '<option value="'.$file['basename'].'">'.$file['filename'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

So the `Subme` Select tag is `echoed` by the PHP script and loads in the div `channels`, all is fine but the function assigned to it by the PHP script 
       onchange="showSubme(this);" 
is not working :-(

this showSubme function is exactly like the showme(str) (given above) and will fire a similar PHP script.

Why it is not working ? did I missed something here ?
I am grateful to all answers!

Comment: where is the showSubme() function? I think it should be within the lstavai.php output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved simply with this: Add a disabled option in the beginning:

```
 <?php 
$q = $_GET['q'];
$files = glob('../dsx/'.$q.'/*.txt');
echo '<select id="Subme" onchange="showSubme(this);">
     <option disabled selected>Please select</option>
 ';
foreach($files as $file) {
    $file = pathinfo($file);    
    echo '<option value="'.$file['basename'].'">'.$file['filename'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this in your code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("country");
```

In your html you have called the id category and not country.

```
<select id="category" onchange="showme(this);">
```

Happy coding, Max

Comment: Oh that'S just because I am struggling with the editor to write my question . It is correctly writting in my html because the final result is there with a nice populated select tag. my problem is the function showSubme which doesn't want to fire: I paste it here:

Comment: function showSubme(strm) {  
  if (strm=="") {
    document.getElementById("details").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","lstchl.php?q="+strm,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

Comment: @karmel what sort of problems are you having with the editor? All you have to do is copy/paste in the relevant source code to your question. Formattubg help keep the clean and clear to read.

Comment: I edited your answer to put the function showSubme. Thank you for your help